# How to custom input file with bootstrap 4

Tags: forms, file, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I want to do like this in webpack bootstrap 4 env :

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#custom-forms

**File browser**

```
<label class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
  <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
</label>
```

How to override the **"placeholder"**  and **"button-label"** value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those values are from CSS:

```
.custom-file-control:lang(en)::after {
  content: "Choose file...";
}

.custom-file-control:lang(en)::before {
  content: "Browse";
}
```